# Reversing order in ng-repeat output using TamperMonkey

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, tampermonkey, angularjs-orderby

So I have this line on a page that provides a list of serial numbers as they are scanned in:

```
<div class='animate' ng-repeat='serialIdEntry in scan.scannedSerialIds track by $index'>
```

Presently each new scanned serial is appended to the bottom of the list, and it would be wildly more efficient and helpful were the order reversed.

Meaning, I need the most recent scan to be at top, and the whole of the list (as displayed) in reverse order.

I *believe* I can accomplish that by adding `| orderBy:'':true"` after the `track by $index` argument. Or by simply replacing that line with one that included the `orderBy` argument.

I suspect the method of updating on that page is AJAX/Angular, and I'm wondering how best to modify the output by way of a TamperMonkey script. I've been reading up on `waitForKeyElements', but that seems to largely speak to appending a new line of code rather than inserting a new snippet inline, or replacing a single line with one that has been modified.

Comment: You can use your browser to edit-in that `| orderBy:'':true"` on the live page, but I don't think that will work.  We need a way to duplicate your issue without having to roll our own webapp that we *think* matches yours.  Is there some way we can see the target page?  If not, make a [mcve] and edit it into your question.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm really limited in terms of being able to actually produce code. So I guess the best bet may be to simply narrow the scope of this question:

IF I wish to insert the orderBy into the existing code using TamperMonkey, is there a graceful way to do so? All I need is for ng-repeat to produce the most recently scanned serial number at the top, rather than the bottom.